# React Native - How to process camera frames in real time while displaying them?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-camera

I'm making an app where I have a camera feed that should be displayed, where the frames of the feed should be processed in real time.

I was thinking of using native modules for the camera feed and processing, but afaik in order to show the frames I'd have to send them through the React Native Bridge, which has a low bandwidth so the feed wouldn't appear in real time.

So I'm looking at having the camera feed and processing on the React Native side, but I need a way of getting the individual frames to process them while also showing the feed in real time.

I know that there are barcode scanners in React Native, so it must be possible to build something that both shows a camera feed and processes its frames.

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated, thanks!